# Why eglswapinterval cannot disable v-sync?

Tags: qt, opengl-es, qml, frame-rate

My environment:

```
qt.scenegraph.general: QSG: basic render loop
qt.scenegraph.general: Using sg animation driver
qt.scenegraph.general: texture atlas dimensions: 2048x2048
qt.scenegraph.general: R/G/B/A Buffers:   8 8 8 0
qt.scenegraph.general: Depth Buffer:      24
qt.scenegraph.general: Stencil Buffer:    8
qt.scenegraph.general: Samples:           0
qt.scenegraph.general: GL_VENDOR:         Imagination Technologies
qt.scenegraph.general: GL_RENDERER:       PowerVR Rogue GE7800
qt.scenegraph.general: GL_VERSION:        OpenGL ES 3.2 build 1.10@5187610
```

I am running a Hello world QML program and config as above.

```
QT_QPA_EGLFS_SWAPINTERVAL=0
QT_QPA_UPDATE_IDLE_TIME=0
QSG_RENDER_LOOP=basic
```

I test the `QT_QPA_EGLFS_SWAPINTERVAL` via `PVRTrace` https://www.imgtec.com/developers/powervr-sdk-tools/pvrtrace/

[image]

it shows the `eglSwapInterval` did set properly as above.
But the problem is the program stuck on 60FPS.
Why I cannot disable the V-Sync.

Comment: What device are you running on?

Comment: @solidpixel hi, R-car M3N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that vsync behavior is entirely platform dependent. In reality `eglSwapInterval()` is actually just hint and it is implementation-defined whether it actually does anything at all. On most platforms it doesn't - e.g. on Android you can neither disable it nor fix FPS at 30. Suggest raising this with the platform provider.